# MinGW g++ `strnlen` was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

currently I'm trying to run some code that I received from lynda.com but it is spitting out an error. The file I'm trying to compile is as follows, only including the calls to `strnlen` (strc.cpp):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>

#include "strc.h"

...

strc::strc() : data(nullptr) {
    msg("default ctor");
}

strc::strc(const char * s) {
    size_t slen = strnlen(s, _maxlen);
    data = new char[slen + 1];
    data[slen] = 0;
    memcpy(data, s, slen);
    msg("cstring ctor");
}

strc::strc(const strc & f) {
    size_t slen = strnlen(f.data, _maxlen);
    data = new char[slen + 1];
    data[slen] = 0;
    memcpy(data, f.data, slen);
    msg("copy ctor");
}
...
```

To compile this I am running:

`g++ -c strc.cpp -o strc.o -std=c++11`

I've tried replacing `cstring` with `string.h` and I've even tried but `std::` in front of `strnlen`. Any help in this matter would be greately appreciated

Comment: Could you please provide us error message? Is it saying, that `strnlen` was not declared in this scope?

Comment: The copy-constructor could use `strlen` and `strcpy` instead, since `f` will already have been limited to under `_maxlen` during `f`'s construction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strnlen` is not a Standard C++ function.  I guess you've previously been using some other compiler which provided this as a non-standard extension.

You will need to change your code to either not call this function; or provide your own function with similar functionality (not calling it `strnlen`).

Comment: I've tried this code with MSVC and it compiles fine, I just assumed that it should work in g++ as well. This isn't my own code, as I mentioned I got it from lynda.com, I'll see what I can do to fix it

Comment: Replaced the calls of `strnlen` to `strlen`, compiles and runs fine

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue... I put this function there

```cpp
static size_t strnlen(const char* s,size_t maxlen) {
    for (size_t i=0; i < maxlen ; i++ ){
        if (s[i] == '\0')
            return i;
    }
    return maxlen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct header for strlen is:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Reference: [strnlen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strnlen)

Comment: The question is asking about `strnlen`, not `strlen`

Comment: Also , `<cstring>` provides all the functions of `<string.h>`

Comment: @M.M Thanks for the highlight, I have corrected my answer. ... just missed 'n' out :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the compiler error is happening because of the command-line flag `-std=c++11`. The C++ version of the header `<cstring>` appears to only have the following related function according to this [cplusplus](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) reference: `std::size_t strlen( const char* str )`. According to this [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strnlen-strnlen-s?view=msvc-170) reference, the function `strnlen`, defined in the C version of the header `<string.h>`, may be more secure than `strlen` since it "calculates the length but doesn't walk past the end of the buffer if the string is unterminated". When I ran this code on GCC 11, it compiled successfully when I changed the command-line flag to `-std=gnu++14` (or later, or even got rid of the flag) which enables the GNU extensions that include the C version of `<string.h>` (you can read more about GNU C extensions at this [GNU](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html) reference). I encountered this same problem while trying to run some code that I received from lynda.com, so you may find the following Makefile helpful that I used to successfully compile a file `unique.cpp` that includes the header `strc.h`:

```
# Unique Pointer Makefile
CXX      = g++
CXXFLAGS = -O3 -funroll-loops -ftree-vectorize -Wall -std=gnu++17 
TARGET   = uni
OBJS     = strc.o unique.o

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) *.o
```

Answer (score -2):

You can replace `strnlen` by following snippet of code 
`strlen (s) < maxlen ? strlen (s) : maxlen`

you can refer at [strnlen](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Length.html)

Comment: Not a good idea. Maybe you use `strnlen` because you are not sure if the string is null-terminated.